# Create an array of POJO's from JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I'm attempting to get multiple POJO's from json that looks something like this

```
  {
  "obj1": {
    "quizowner": "testacccc",
    "question": "questionB",
    "answer": "6",
    "directions": "directionsB",
    "quizname": "quiz Name",
    "subject": "subjB",
    "options": "5, 7, 6",
    "type": "CHECKBOX"
  },
  "obj0": {
    "quizowner": "testacccc",
    "question": "questionA",
    "answer": "3",
    "directions": "directionsA",
    "quizname": "quiz Name",
    "subject": "subjA",
    "options": "1,2,3",
    "type": "MULTIPLECHOICE"
  }
}
```

I have done this before utilizing JACKSON, but only with a single object. There could be up to 50 of these in obj's, and I'm not sure how to access them.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("questions")
public Response addQuiz(Question question, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {


}
```

How could I map the JSON into an array of Question pojo's? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Does the JSON represent list/array?  It should look like `[{"obj1":{}}, {"obj2":{}}]`

Comment: I updated how it looks with two objs. Are the brackets needed? I am directly converting a JSONObject to a string @AlexRudenko

Comment: Try with `public Response addQuiz(Map<String, Question> questions, @Context HttpHeaders headers)`. You can always treat a `JSON Object` as a `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

If your incoming json is like `{"obj1":{"question":"questionB","answer":"6","directions":"directionsB","quizname":"quiz Name","subject":"subjB","options":"5, 7, 6","type":"CHECKBOX"}}|`

Then **one way** is to create a Class like

```
public class QuestionBase {
  @JsonProperty("obj1")
  public Question question;
  :
  : //getters n setters
}
```

and use it like

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("questions")
public Response addQuiz(QuestionBase questionBase, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
   questionBase.getQuestion() ----> will give you the question details

}
```

**Second way** I can suggest to to write a Custom JSON Deserialization. You can see one example over [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: With this method, would I instead say addQuiz(String jsonString), instead of putting a pojo as the parameter?

Comment: @johnlacrosse can you check my updated answer

Comment: I have multiple obj's in my JSON though. Wont this only work for one?

Comment: @johnlacrosse can you show me the exact json, the one which you have shown in incomplete. Also does the key `obj1`, `obj2` dynamic one